# Replacing the values of an "L" shape section of a Python 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have the following 2d array:

```
[[a, a, a, a],
 [a, a, b, a],
 [a, a, b, a],
 [a, c, c, a],
 [a, a, a, a]]
```

And I want to transform it into the following:

```
[[a, a, a, a],
 [a, a, d, a],
 [a, a, d, a],
 [a, d, d, a],
 [a, a, a, a]]
```

I am currently doing it in 2 steps: like arr[1:4,2]=d and arr[3, 1:3]=d

Is there a way to do it in only one step, which would also not impact the performance?

Comment: You can assign values to variables in one line in python: ```a = b = 5```. Does this answer your question?

Comment: `arr[1:4,2]=d` That's not valid Python syntax for lists.  Are you using something like numpy?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned I am using numpy arrays. I am just kinda wondering if there is a way to select the area I wish to change in one assignment instead of doing 2 separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not possible, you can't get L shape in just on slicing, need at least 2 slicings to form an L.